# How to call a jquery function on load and return boolean value MVC ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an image tag in my MVC View which I want to display only when the boolean value returned from controller is true. I have written a jquery function which gets called on image load, which in turn calls a controller method and returns boolean value. However, the jquery function never seems to get called on Image load. I have very limited knowledge of Jquery and not sure if I am calling it right.

```
 <div class="imageHolder">
     <img id="icon" data-userId="@Model.Users[i].Id" src="~/Images/Icon.png" onclick="location.href='/UserDetails/GetUserID?userID=@Model.Users[i].Id'" />
 </div>
```

Jquery function:

```
$("#icon").load(function () {
            $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url:"UserDetails/CheckIfUserDataExists?userId=" + $('#icon').attr('data-userId'),
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             dataType: "json",
             success: function (data) {
                    if (data == "true") {
                        $('#icon').show();
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#icon').hide();
                    }
              },
       });
   }
```

Controller Method:

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult CheckIfUserDataExists(int userId)
        {
           if(userRepository.CheckIfUserHasData(userId))
            {
                return Json(true);
            }
           else
            {
                return Json(false);
            }
        }
```

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: why not just put it on your model so you can process it when the page loads rather than waiting and then doing an ajax call? `Model.UserHasData = userRepository.CheckIfUserHasData(Model.Users[i].Id);` or add a property directly to the user class - `public bool HasData { get { return userRepository.CheckIfUserHasData(this.Id); }}`

Comment: @Pete Thanks for your reply. That is how I was intending to do it the first time. But when I create the view model, I get all the users from the DB and I wasn't sure how to pass individual userId's and get the boolean back.

Comment: I would then either make an extension method for the user or put it as a property on the user so you can just call `if (Model.Users[i].HasData()) {}`

Comment: @Pete Thank you for your suggestion. I just put the boolean in the model directly and did Model.UserHasData = userRepository.CheckIfUserHasData(Model.Users[i].Id); and works as expected

Answer (score 0):

If the image is cached the image will load before the event is bound. Try the below.

```
$("#icon").one("load", function () {
    $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url:"UserDetails/CheckIfUserDataExists?userId=" + $('#icon').attr('data-userId'),
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json",
         success: function (data) {
                if (data == "true") {
                    $('#icon').show();
                }
                else {
                    $('#icon').hide();
                }
          },
   });
}).each(function () {
    if (this.complete) $(this).load();
});
```

The `.one` handler is executed at most once per element per event type so it will run only once. Looping through with the .each function will ensure it will fire the load event even if it is cached.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery snippet to run code once image has loaded:

```
$('#icon').attr('src', '~/Images/Icon.png').load(function () {
    // run Ajax code
    console.log('#icon image loaded');
});
```